# Check if function returns true to execute another function

Tags: javascript

I have written a form validation using JS which ends with return(true);

```
function check() {
  ....validation code
  return(true);
}
```

All I want is, need to check if check() function returns true, I want to execute another function.

Code I have tried is as follows:

```
if(check() === true) {
  function() {
    //Another function code
  }
}
```

Comment: `check` can return just `true` also you don't need to use `===` `if(check())` is fine

Comment: Adding to what Alex said, Just do `if (check()) { ... }`

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because the answer seems to be in the question itself.

Comment: With respect to that function you want to execute if `check()` evaluates as `true` - is it actually defined somewhere else outside that conditional?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should use `return true;` and your if statement doesn't need the `=== true` comparison.

```
function check() {
  //validation code
  return true;
}

if(check()) {
  //Another function code
 }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/99ja37mn/)**

Comment: Was just trying to maintain consistency with the direction the OPs code was heading... its really probably not necessary.

Comment: _"All I want is, to check if `check()` returns true, to execute another function."_ The OP's code was wrong if that's what he wants to do. Fix the code to match the requirement, instead of changing the results to match the OP's code.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, `return` is not a function, you can just do this:

```
return true;
```

Now, to only execute `myFunction` if `check` returns `true`, you can do this:

```
check() && myFunction()
```

This is shorthand for:

```
if(check()){
    myFunction();
}
```

You don't need to compare the return value of `check` with `true`. It's already an boolean.

Now, instead of `myFunction()`, you can have any JavaScript code in that `if` statement. If you actually want to use, for example, `myFunction`, you have to make sure you've defined it somewhere, first:

```
function myFunction() {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your first code snippet. `return` is a keyword, what you are trying to do is to execute it as a function.

```
function check() {
....validation code
return true;
}
```

You'll need to change your 2nd snippet slightly, to execute the function too however... The simplest way is to wrap it as an anonymous function using curly braces:

```
if(check()) {
       (function() {
                    //Another function code
       })();
 }
```

Comment: That `if` is completely useless... function statements like that get hoisted, there is no block scope in JS, just function scope. Try this:  `if(false){function test(){console.log(1)}} test();`

Comment: @Cerbrus: You sample isn't the same as what I included. The function declaration may get hoisted up, but the execution doesn't - see http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/3zn8m6vc/

Comment: My code sample matches what was in your answer before your edit. Now you have an utterly useless IIFE in an `if` statement. Take a look at what the OP requested: _"All I want is, to check if check() returns true, to execute another function."_

Comment: @Cerbrus - true, the function doesn't *need* to be declared there.

Comment: My point is that this answer is completely missing the point of the question. The OP just wants to run a function if a statement is `true`. IIFE's have _no_ business here. Not to mention that `return(something)` doesn't try to execute anything as a function. That's just some brackets wrapped around a return statement's parameter.

Answer (score -2):

You're not calling the function in your affirmative clause, only declaring it. To call an anonymous function do this:

```
(function (){...})()
```

Answer (score -2):

You could type

```
$this.myFunction=function(){
//code here
}
```

and to execute some code if a the `myFunction` function is true, you could use booleans
such as e.g.

```
if(//your function is true){
```

and so on