# Simple Check Function with node.js, pg-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

I am trying to write a simple `check()` function following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28069688/6819862). The function successfully prints out "True!" but the return value of the function is `undefined` when I do `console.log(submitModels.verifyOrganizationString(formInputs.organizationString));`. How can I get the function to return `true` and `false`?

Right now the function only returns `"Invalid organization string"` even when the string is valid.

I am thinking this result has to do with the `pg-promise` library, but am not sure.

In the file `submit.js`, I have:

```
function verifyOrganizationString(organizationString) {
  db.one("select * from organizations where organization_string=$1", [organizationString])
    .then(data => {
        console.log("True!");
        return true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("False!");
        return false;
    });
}

module.exports = {
  verifyOrganizationString,
};
```

In another file, I have

```
const submitModels = require('../models/submit.js');

function proccessSubmission(req, res) {
  var formInputs = req.body;
  console.log(submitModels.verifyOrganizationString(formInputs.organizationString));

  if (submitModels.verifyOrganizationString(formInputs.organizationString)) {
    submitModels.insertIntoDatabase(formInputs);
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    res.send("Invalid organization string");
  }

}
```

Comment: you need to clear your concept about promises because you are using promises illegally sort of anti-pattern. Remember one thing the values returned from any of `.then` or `.catch` will only be accessed by the next chained `.then` or `.catch` this is because the values returned is actually a promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to both invalid use of promises and bad use of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

If you want the function to return `true`/`false` depending on whether a record is found, change the function to this:

```
function verifyOrganizationString(organizationString) {
    return db.oneOrNone("select * from organizations where organization_string = $1",
                         organizationString, a => !!a);
}
```

Then you can use it as one would a regular promise:

```
verifyOrganizationString('bla-bla')
    .then(data => {
       // data = true/false
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

See also: [SELECT ⇒ INSERT](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/examples/select-insert.md) examples.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the `a => !!a` is doing?

Comment: @cpage [The method's documentation is quite clear on that](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.oneOrNone).

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting undefined is because 'verifyOrganizationString' doesn't actually return anything. You need to return the promise created by your db.one chain.

Although the method will still not return true or false in that case but the Boolean wrapped in another promise so that you can chain the result of your verify function the same way you did with the result of db.one.

Comment: Would the better approach be [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/chaining-queries)?

Comment: @cpage that's nothing to do with your broken code ;) Your problem is that you misuse promises. You need to learn how to use promises correctly.